# How could user cancel the consent during the sign-in

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I develop a program to sign in azure users,during the sign in,user need to consent the permission,but after that,how would a user revoke the consent?
On azure portal,I can't find somewhere user can revoke the permission.
I am new to azure,any help is appreciate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could revoke individual user consent through the My Apps Portal(https://myapps.microsoft.com/) . On that portal , for apps where you individually consented as a user, you can click "Remove" which will revoke consent for the application.

I would highly recommend you read [this blog](http://shawntabrizi.com/aad/revoking-consent-azure-active-directory-applications/) which explain more about revoking consent for Azure Active Directory Applications . This article also includes scenario for using the Azure Portal to remove tenant wide consent.